FFmpeg not connecting to the NamedPipeServerStream
I am implementing a function to merge audio and video into a single stream using FFmpeg tool.
The problem I have right now is that FFmpeg is not connecting to the pipes and I have no idea why. Can someone help me with this issue?
Questions I already read:

ffmpeg process how to read from pipe to pipe in c#
ffmpeg output pipeing to named windows pipe
How to use pipe in ffmpeg within c#
Using pipes with FFMpeg as an input

Arguments:
-i "\\.\pipe\FFmpeg_8daf7" -i "\\.\pipe\FFmpeg_46100" -c:v copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -shortest -f mp4 pipe:1

The error I am receiving:
[in#0 @ 0000015395b97600] Error opening input: No such file or directory
Error opening input file \\.\pipe\FFmpeg_8daf7.
Error opening input files: No such file or directory

My code:
public static async Task<MemoryStream> OverwriteAudioInVideo(
    Stream video, Stream audio, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var videoPipeName = GetPipeName();
    var audioPipeName = GetPipeName();

    var arguments = GetOverwriteAudioInVideoCommand(audioPipeName, videoPipeName);

    var videoPipeTask = CreatePipeAndWriteDataAsync(videoPipeName, video, cancellationToken);
    var audioPipeTask = CreatePipeAndWriteDataAsync(audioPipeName, audio, cancellationToken);

    using var process = CreateFFmpegProcess(arguments);

    process.OutputDataReceived += OnDataReceived;
    process.ErrorDataReceived += OnDataReceived;

    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine(); // For debugging purposes only
                                   // Will cause exception in
                                   // 'ReadProcessResultToMemoryStreamAsync'
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

    await Task.WhenAll(videoPipeTask, audioPipeTask);

    await process.WaitForExitAsync(cancellationToken);

    process.ErrorDataReceived -= OnDataReceived;
    process.OutputDataReceived -= OnDataReceived;

    return await ReadProcessResultToMemoryStreamAsync(process, cancellationToken);
}

private static async Task CreatePipeAndWriteDataAsync(
    string name, Stream input, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        using var pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream(
            name,
            PipeDirection.Out,
            1,
            PipeTransmissionMode.Byte,
            PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

        Debug.WriteLine($"Waiting for connection on pipe {name}");
        await pipe.WaitForConnectionAsync(cancellationToken);
        Debug.WriteLine($"Connected to pipe {name}");

        await input.CopyToAsync(pipe, cancellationToken);
        pipe.Close();
        Debug.WriteLine($"Data written to pipe {name}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Error creating or writing to pipe {name}: {ex.Message}");
        throw;
    }
}

private static async Task<MemoryStream> ReadProcessResultToMemoryStreamAsync(
    Process process, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var result = new MemoryStream();
    var buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead;

    do
    {
        bytesRead = await process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, cancellationToken);
        await result.WriteAsync(buffer.AsMemory(0, bytesRead), cancellationToken);
    } while (bytesRead > 0);

    return result;
}

private static string GetOverwriteAudioInVideoCommand(string audioPipeName, string videoPipeName)
{
    const string CommandFormat
        = "-i \"{0}\" -i \"{1}\" -c:v copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -shortest -f mp4 pipe:1";

    var result = string.Format(CommandFormat, audioPipeName, videoPipeName);

    Debug.WriteLine(result);

    return result;
}

private const string ExecutablePath = "ExternalBinaries\\ffmpeg.exe";

private static Process CreateFFmpegProcess(string arguments) => new()
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(ExecutablePath, arguments)
    {
#if !DEBUG
        CreateNoWindow = true,
#endif
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    }
};

private static string GetPipeName()
{
    var name = $"FFmpeg_{Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")[..5]}";

    Debug.WriteLine(name);

    return RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)
        ? $"\\\\.\\pipe\\{name}"
        : $"unix:{Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), $"CoreFxPipe_{name}")}";
}

private static void OnDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    => Debug.WriteLine(e.Data);


Read this answer carefully again! ffmpeg output pipeing to named windows pipe

@shingo,  What I missed there?

The names used to create the pipes have no prefix.

You are right. I've posted an answer. Thanks! But now I have another issue - when I am copying input stream into the pipe - I am getting the following exception: System.IO.IOException: 'Pipe is broken.'. Any idea why?

You may ask a new question and add some details about the exception. This error 'Pipe is broken.' is not very helpful.

All credits to @shingo. When creating a pipe, there should be no \\.\pipe\ prefix in it's name. This prefix has to be included in the FFmpeg arguments only.
